# Find the network address with IP address in jQuery

Tags: jquery, ip

Suppose we have an IP address such as: `192.168.1.1/24`, how to find the network address from this address?

I tried to cut out the IP address to replace the last character by `0`, but it isn't working.

```
$('.ip').val().replace($('.ip').val().split('/')[0].split('.')[3], 0);
```

Where `$('.ip')` is the selector of an input whose class name is `ip`.

Returns `092.168.1.1/24`. The expected result is rather this : `192.168.1.0/24`

Comment: [do you need something like this?](http://jsfiddle.net/hosvty3x/2/)

Comment: what if you have a different mask?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will give you the desired result:

```
$('.ip').val(function(_, value) {
   return value.replace(/\d+(\/\d+)$/, '0$1');
});
```

`\d+(\/\d+)$` replaces one digit or more, which is followed by a forward slash (`/`) and one digit it more (at the end of the given string).

`0$1` is the replacement, so `0` followed by the value which matched the expression between `()` (in the example this is `/24`)

Just a side note, this has no concept of CIDR notation (ie. if the CIDR was changed the result would be the same - it's a simple string replacement)

Comment: Excellent explanation. Thank you a lot ! :) I suppose that I always have an IP address with the correct CIDR.

Answer (score 1):

Using a third party service might be your best option:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.getJSON("http://jsonip.com/?callback=?", function (data) {
        var ip = data.ip;
    });
});
```

Something else you can try is using Jquery's ajax function to get the content of a PHP file you create on your server, and in that php file you echo the user's IP address using

```
$ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
echo "IP address= $ip";
```

Comment: Sources: 
http://stackoverflow.com/a/19953367/3994654
http://www.plus2net.com/php_tutorial/php_ip.php

Comment: My first solution works without any php, fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/rBL3D/80/